# iOS 13, crashes with Photos framework, PHCompositeMediaResult class

Tags: ios, swift

After new iOS release in our app become crashing with PHCompositeMediaResult. What I see in Crashlytics.

> [PHCompositeMediaResult isPlaceholder]
>
> [PHCompositeMediaResult isDegraded]
>
> [PHCompositeMediaResult isCancelled]

Any idea what can we do with this?

**Edit**

Stacktrace:

```
Crashed: com.apple.photos.imageManagerCache
0  libobjc.A.dylib                0x1b12b8190 objc_msgSend + 16
1  CoreFoundation                 0x1b146ec04 -[__NSDictionaryM objectForKeyedSubscript:] + 180
2  Photos                         0x1bc7f385c -[PHCompositeMediaResult isPlaceholder] + 36
3  Photos                         0x1bc84b978 -[PHCachingImageManager _canPopulateCacheForResult:] + 56
4  Photos                         0x1bc84e588 __90-[PHCachingImageManager additionalWorkForImageRequestCompletedWithResult:request:context:]_block_invoke + 64
5  libdispatch.dylib              0x1b1260658 _dispatch_call_block_and_release + 24
6  libdispatch.dylib              0x1b12611cc _dispatch_client_callout + 16
7  libdispatch.dylib              0x1b120d524 _dispatch_lane_serial_drain$VARIANT$mp + 608
8  libdispatch.dylib              0x1b120df18 _dispatch_lane_invoke$VARIANT$mp + 420
9  libdispatch.dylib              0x1b1217400 _dispatch_workloop_worker_thread + 588
10 libsystem_pthread.dylib        0x1b12b0fa8 _pthread_wqthread + 276
11 libsystem_pthread.dylib        0x1b12b3ae4 start_wqthread + 8
```

Comment: Full Stacktrace maybe?

Comment: @Larme it's internal error. All points in stacktrace contains in system library. Stacktrase was added on the end.

Answer (score 0):

This appears to just happen in iOS 13.0.0. I don't have any instances of it happening on 13.1, 13.1.1, or 13.1.2... So it was probably a bug in the OS that they quickly figured out and fixed. Hopefully not many users stay on 13.0.0 for long. Maybe the "what to do about this?" answer is just to do nothing.